# Unit Tests: How to Assert? Asserting results returned or that a method was called on a mock?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nunit, nsubstitute

I am trying to find out the best way to Assert, should I be creating an object with what i should return and check that it has equal to the expected result ?

Or should I be running a method against a mock to ensure that the method was actually called.

I have seen this done both ways, I wondered if anyone has any best practices for this.

Of course, it's quicker and easier to write a unit test to assert that a method was called on the mock but quicker and easier is not always the best way - although sometimes it can be.

What does everyone assert on, that a method has been called or assert the results that were returned ?

Of course its not best practice to do more than 1 assert in a unit test so maybe the answer is to actually assert the results and that the method was called ? So I would create 2 unit tests, 1 to check the results and 1 to check that the method was called.

But now thinking about this, maybe this is going too far, if I get a result that I suppose I can assume that my mock method was called.

Comment: these are not mutually exclusive concerns.  You can do one, the other or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In between testing that a method has been called and testing the value that it returns is another possibly more important test: that it was called with the correct parameters.

A very common case these days would a method you're writing that uses some HTTP library to retrieve data from a REST API. You don't want to actually make HTTP requests in your tests so you mock the HTTP client `get()` method. On the one hand your mock might just return some canned JSON response like (Using RSpec in Ruby as an example):

```
http_mock.stub(:get).and_return('{result: 5}')
```

You then test that you can properly parse this and return some correct value based on the response.

You could also test that the HTTP `get()` method is called, but it's more important to test that it's called *with the correct parameters*. In the case of an API, your method probably has to format a URL with query parameters and you need to test that it does that correctly. The assertion would look something like (again with RSpec):

```
http_mock.should_receive(:get).with('http:/example.com/some_endpoint?some_param=x')
```

This test is really a prerequisite to the previous test, and simply testing that `get()` was called wouldn't confirm much. For instance, it would tell you if you were incorrectly formatting the URL.